Connection issue inBluestacks 5
I use Bluestacks 5 for playing game. recently I have an issue. when I try to play using wifi or ethernet, match doesn't start. using vpn solves this problem but have huge ping issue. but when I use PPPoE connection, there is no issue at all. ping is soo much better.
how to solve the issue for ethernet or wifi?
Using PPPoE connection solves the problem but I need to use other devices also so that's not an option for me.
